# MVC 5 (vNext) using WebAPI to logon user and or Register user (Authorization and Authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

Ok,

I have a standard MVC app which users can register and logon. I now have started to create a WebAPI which will allow users of Non-Web based clients to register and logon. All this is done in ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and MVC 6.

The API POST is how the User logs on at the moment (but may not be the best method) and has this code:

```
// POST api/Raptor
        // Attempts to log the user in.
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]UserLogin user)
        {
            var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        }
```

This brings up the error:

> Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'optionsAccessor' of
>   'UserManager.UserManager(IUserStore,
>   IOptions, IPasswordHasher,
>   IEnumerable>,
>   IEnumerable>, IUserNameNormalizer,
>   IEnumerable>,
>   IEnumerable)'   CCSLABS.ASP.NET
>   5.0   RaptorLoginController.cs    35

To the Questions:

1. How do I solve the Error above?
2. Is Authorization shared between WebAPI controllers as it is with MVC controllers?
3. Is the WebAPI the correct way of doing the following?

Have a non-web client connect to my web server. Create a User if registering or log them on if they are already registered. This is so I can keep track of the User's statistics from their off-line client.

Using a Queue on the Webserver send tasks to the client when it asks. Receive completed tasks from the client when it sends them.

Comment: Do you mean ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and MVC 6?

Comment: Yup - thanks for that, updated

Comment: I don't know the answer, but keep in mind that these technologies are in preview and could contain any number of bugs as they are not release candidates yet.

Comment: I'm stumped.  Looking at the vNext source for UserManager https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserManager.cs clearly shows optional parameters for every param other than the first, store, which you seem to successfully provide.

Comment: There is no Web API authentication story of yet. But here are some other important comments. If you want an API controller, note that we only support attribute routing for defining APIs, and the the GetById/Post translating to actions with no names is not supported anymore.